# Asp.net mvc 4 - pass specific model data to view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm making a website where all text on the site will be editable from an admin-page.
The problem is that I have no idea how to send in **the right** post to the view.

For example, I want to pass the "Welcome-post" to the home view, how do I select this specific post from the model data? I've seen that I can find posts by their ID, `db.Posts.Find(1)`, is this a good idea or should I be more specific and use a string?

Compared to SQL it could look like:

```
"SELECT * FROM test WHERE title='welcome'"
```

Is there any similar method to use in order to find specific model data without using the primary key? Would a simple IF-loop suffice?

```
Ex, If(Post.Title == "Welcome"){...}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The model data should only contain the detail needed for the view. Your controller would populate that model beforehand. The question sounds more related to querying the data to populate the model. If I misunderstood, please correct me.

ID is the most efficient way to identify your post, but before you can get to the individual post you may need to identify the post in question to get the ID. In which case I would suggest extending your entity to include a category.

From the results of your query, could could select a results ID and query the full details from that

The SQL would look like

```
Select ID, Title FROM Test t WHERE c.CategoryName = 'Welcome'
INNER JOIN Categories c ON c.CategoryId=t.CategoryId
```

LINQ might be something like

```
var welcomePosts = db.Posts.Where(post=>post.CategoryName=="Welcome")
                           .Select(post=>new{Title, Id});
```

In the real world you would probably have a respository accepting a predicate or some other generic means of selecting

```
public abstract IEnumerable<Post> GetPosts(Func<Post, bool> predicate)
```

Doing it this way you can index your categories. The above queries may result in multiple posts coming back with that category, then an edit button beside each one could then lead on to pull back the specifics using the ID?

Answer (score 0):

ID will be the best way to identify a post. Unsure as to your exact setup, but you may well be able to have muiple posts with the same title

You should create a view model that accurately reflects your Post and populate this from your repository before passing to the view.